# How to use object dynamically based on input?

Tags: javascript

I have 3 objects:

```
let Obj1 = {Obj1};
let Obj2 = {Obj2};
let Obj3 = {Obj3};
```

and I need to perform some action on them:

```
Obj1.indexOf(value) === - 1 ? do_something() : do_something_else();
```

But I want to choose the object to perform this operation on based on an input.

The input is a string describing the object name = "obj1", "obj2", "obj3".

Currently I am using if-else conditions to choose which object to perform the operation on:

```
if (input === "obj1") {
    Obj1.indexOf(value) === - 1 ? do_something() : do_something_else();
} else if (input === "obj2") {
    Obj2.indexOf(value) === - 1 ? do_something() : do_something_else();
} else if (input === "obj3") {
    Obj3.indexOf(value) === - 1 ? do_something() : do_something_else();
}
```

Is there a way to do it more dynamically?

Comment: Are these custom objects? Natively they don't have the `indexOf` property. Or did you mean arrays?

Comment: You are correct, they are arrays actually in my code, but I just refer to it as Object as well (I didn't think that would make difference because the question is about the other part - do you want me to change it?)